# SQL query to count frequency of transactions done in last 30 days

Tags: java, sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a question regarding how to do a SQL query or java spark SQL query that counts frequency of transactions done in last 30 days by a certain credit card number.

The timestamps are from Jan 2019 to 31 Dec 2020 so I need to somehow also keep in mind the year and month.

I have only one table : `transactions`

Do you guys have some idea?

My table:

[image]

Comment: I have no idea if any of these are valid, but did you really just post (customer!) credit card numbers on the internet?

Comment: ahahah these are simulated ccnum

Comment: For SQL queries you can use a group by on cc number and a trunc of the transaction date. trunc date functions depends on the database.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps!!

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.dataframe
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

if __name__ == '__main__':
    spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('Medium').master('local[1]').getOrCreate()
    df = spark.read.format('csv').option("header", "true").option("delimiter", "|").load(
        "/Users/dshanmugam/Desktop/so_2.csv")


    def get_count(df: pyspark.sql.dataframe, cc_num: int):
        df.filter("CC_NUM={}".format(cc_num)).filter(col('TXN_DATE') <= date_sub(current_date(), 30)).show()

    get_count(df,'123456')
```